# Find child elements in another child element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, find

I have the following structure of elements:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="list-elements">
        <div class="element-item">Element 1</div>
        <div class="element-item active">Element 2</div>
        <div class="element-item">Element 3</div>
        <div class="element-item active">Element 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="another-elements">
        <div class="element-item active">Element 1</div>
        <div class="element-item">Element 2</div>
        <div class="element-item">Element 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to get only the elements `.main > .list-elements > .element-item.active`.

I have unsuccessfully tried the following code:

```
$(".main").find(".list-elements .element-item.active");
```

Comment: You are going to have to provide more information.  That selector is valid.

Comment: `.list-elements .element-item.active` says find class "element-item active" that are children of class "list-elements" which is exactly what your markup is showing

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w9dufwsr/  works fine

Comment: Do you know that `.find()` returns a collection of elements?

Comment: Thank you very much everyone and sorry for the question. I was having errors with some variables and that's why I did not work correctly. Now it works with my selector.

Comment: @Smark if the question does not reflect what your issue was, and the answer is just reiterating that it works as it is presented, then really this question is more applicable for deletion, as it really offers no new information to future readers about what the issue was and how it was fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you only trying to grab `collection of elements` using `.find()` and did nothing, that's why you confused that your code is not working.

You have to grab some data through that `collection of elements` and then you come to know that your code is working fine.

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".main").find(".list-elements .element-item.active").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="list-elements">
      <div class="element-item">Element 1</div>
      <div class="element-item active">Element 2</div>
      <div class="element-item">Element 3</div>
      <div class="element-item active">Element 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="another-elements">
      <div class="element-item active">Element 1</div>
      <div class="element-item">Element 2</div>
      <div class="element-item">Element 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```